# Cannot do SSH or Remote Desktop Connection into my office computer?

Tags: windows-8, ssh, remote-desktop, connection

I've my office computer which is connected to my university wifi account. Whatever I do I'm not able to connect to my Office PC. I have enabled remote desktop and I have put all firewall on off. This is on windows 8, I would really appreciate guidance on how I can trouble shoot the issue.
I'm trying to do remote desktop connection to my office pc which is windows 8 from my laptop which has windows 7. My wireless network should have some kind of firewalls, but I do not have the details to that. If anybody can tell how I can find it, I'll get and update the question.
Office PC is located at my school which is 20 minutes from my place.

Comment: Not enough info in question yet to really help... Can you add more information about both computers as well as network layout? Are there additional firewalls between you and your computer?  Are both computers running windows?  What ssh server are you running on the office pc?

Comment: when you say "Office PC", do you mean the PC in your office at your workplace, halfway across town, or do you mean the one in your home office, down the hall from your present location, 1st door on the right?

Comment: Have you talked with the University's IT department? They likely have RDP blocked from external networks. VPN would likely be required as step 1.

Comment: @FrankThomas he says 20 minutes away!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem lies in your university's security measures. You can talk to guys in your IT group, but I think they might be unwilling to open up a port to allow connections to your work pc.

In this case, a VPN is possible solution, but an even simpler one, given that you must already have putty installed on your pc, is to set up a "reverse tunnel" from your work pc to your home pc. It can be done with putty: [this link shows you  how to do it](http://www.smythies.com/~doug/network/reverse_ssh_tunnel/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that will work best for your situation:

1. **Using Remote Desktop Connection** - You should talk to your Network Administrators to inquire about what Ports are available or
   even for that matter, if your campus has a    policy on remote
   desktop from home. Some universities have special software besides
   Remote Desktop like Citrix offered. But if it does not, you will
   need **TCP Port 3389** to be open. That is the port Remote Desktop
   uses. Your IT department should be able to assist you with setting Remote Desktop up if it is generally allowed at your university.
2. **Online Services** - Another option is online services such as [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) or [GoToMyPC](http://gotomypc.com). Both are paid services, but LogMeIn
   has a free option as well. This can't be guaranteed as secure and
   I'm sure should probably be avoided in a professional environment.